# What sits in place of the controller in WPF apps

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Most applications today are web apps. And as such, most of the guides and examples are written for web apps. Where I work, we are making WPF application, and there is one thing I cannot figure out:

- *What sits in place of the controller, in a WPF application (using the MVVM pattern)?*

To elaborate:

In web applications,  the UI typically talks to a controller over HTTP. The controller then talks to services/repositories/etc (depending on the architecture).

I have yet to see a clear example of the communication between the UI and back-end in a WPF application.

The examples I have seen either uses a very tight coupling (typically in tutorials) or an HTTP backend (which basically makes it a web app). So if you want the advantages of the loose coupling from the HTTP architecture, but it all has to be in a single app, how do I achieve this?

Comment: So basically this question is a comparison between MVC and MVVM, is that correct?

Comment: Like many web frameworks, WPF says nothing about how the application talks to backend services.  Technically ASP.NET is MVC but just because alot of the tutorials automatically include databases doesn't mean the DB layer is part of MVC

Comment: ...in saying that, what you describe is a common problem and reasonably popular approach is to inject a service/facade/proxy interface into the View Model and have the former do all the nitty gritty, leaving all the MVVM pure GUI-related as it should

Comment: The question is based on the use of MVVM. I have tried to clarify that.

Comment: Typically you have a bunch of backend services, and the VM's talk directly to these. There's loose coupling between the VM's and services. You sometimes still see a Controller, but that's typically more for managing things like navigation

Comment: Have a look at some guides, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)

Comment: @canton7 so what do these services return? The entire model, or just an interface with the properties you want the ViewModel to see?

Comment: @Noceo I've never written an MVVM app which had an "entire model". I always have individual services which perform specific roles. Maybe there's a service managing user authentication, one managing navigation, one managing access to some backend, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVVM, the view binds to a view model class. The view model class may be injected with models or services.

Let's for example say that you want to display a list of some items that you receive from some REST API.

In the view, you would define an `ItemsControl` that binds to a collection property of the view model:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

You may also have a button that binds to a command that is responsible for fetching the data:

The view model may be implemented something like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IRestService _service;

    public ViewModel(IRestService service)
    {
        _service = service;

        GetDataCommand = new RelayCommand(GetData);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> _items;
    public IEnumerable<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Items)); }
    }

    public ICommand GetDataCommand { get; }

    private async void GetData(object _)
    {
        var data = await Task.Run(() => _service.GetData());
        Items = data;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

`RelayCommand` is a custom implementation of the ICommand interface that executes an `Action<object>`. Most implementations you'll find online doesn't support `async`/`await`, i.e. you cannot await the command. That's why `GetData` returns `void` instead of `Task` in the sample above. The service method is called on a background thread to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: One question though. If you use Entity Framework, the context is typically injected into the service (as far as I know). Don’t you risk, that if you stay too long on the same view, then the service (and hence the context) will be too long lived?  Normally the context is supposed to be use and dispose?

Comment: In an enterprise scenario, the context is typically short lived and resides in a data access layer that may be access directly from the view model or through a service.

Comment: Interesting... Would you then handle the dependency injection (assuming you use this) in the data access layer, without the knowledge of the upper layers?

Comment: The dependency injection of what?

Comment: Oh sorry. Of the EF context... Again, assuming that you do inject it to the DA layer...

Comment: Like I said, EF lives only in the DAL. Whether you inject it in the DAL class or not makes no difference. Or maybe I don't understand your question?

Comment: I was thinking that the injection would normally be done by the UI, as this is the entry point (main) of the application. So the UI would have to know about the context and the DA layer (unless the context is passed through the services). Assuming that we are not using any frameworks for the DI. Or am I wrong?

Comment: If you set up your dependency injection in a bootstrapper in the client application, yes, you would reference the DAL directly from there. But how is this related to your original question?

Comment: it wasn’t really :-). I was just trying to figure out exactly how to use your answer in practice. Thanks!